# What syntax should I use when instantly running an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I was just wondering which of these are better or worse, or if there's any difference at all

```
(function(){ ... })();
(function(){ ... }());
```

Comment: they're equivalent - it doesn't matter.

Comment: The first one is the commonly used form, so id's stick with the first one.

Comment: @squint: duplicate of duplicate of duplicate of duplicate or what?

Comment: @Bergi: Sure. Why not?